# Windows 7: Computer does not enter automatic standby

Tags: windows-7, sleep, standby

My Windows 7 PC is set to automatically enter standby ("sleep mode") after 30 minutes. For some reason it stopped working a few days ago (it keeps on running). Is there some systematic way to determine what is preventing the system from automatically entering sleep mode after the designated idle time?

Manually sending the machine to sleep works fine. The monitor also enters power save mode automatically, so the "idling detection" of Windows seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running "powercfg -energy" from command line. Start it with admin privileges. It should tell you if there are some problems with your config.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the information I needed. In case anyone is curious: Apparently, my on-board sound chip did not play well with the default Windows 7 sound driver: `powercfg -energy` listed "High Definition Audio Device" as "prevent[ing] the system from automatically entering sleep". Replacing the generic driver with the sound chip driver from the motherboard manufacturer solved the issue (and added yet another useless icon to my systray... oh, well, at least Windows 7 hides them by default).

Comment: That icon might (or might not) as well be vanquished. Its app must have been installed together with the driver you got from the motherboard manufacturer. Many times these apps are some advanced volume/balance/whatever controllers. Most of their features are available from the Windows Sound Mixer or Speaker properties so if you don't need them you should exclude it from the startup. It's worth a try. The drivers will load anyway. At least, they should.

Answer (score 1):

after running `powercfg -energy` I assume there is a Error for `\FileSystem\srvnet`. This is the media sharing server i believe.

Turn off media sharing. easiest way is to go to HomeGroup settings and Leave the Homegroup. this will turn off Media sharing. This should sort it out.

now if you run `powercfg -energy` again that error should disappear.

Let us know if this solves the issue.
thanks

Comment: As it turned out, media sharing was not the culprit in this case, see my comment on user30539's answer. Thanks anyway for your help!